# Do I need to close pyodbc sql server connection when reading the data into the Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I am confused how to use context manager with `pyodbc` connection. As far as I know, it is usually necessary to close the database connection and using context manager is a good practice for that (for pyodbc, I saw some examples which closes the cursor only). Long story short, I am creating a python app which pulls data from sql server and want to read them into a `Pandas Dataframe`.

I did some search on using `contextlib` and wrote an script `sql_server_connection`:

```
import pyodbc
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_db_connection(server, database):
    """
    Context manager to automatically close DB connection. 
    """
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    try:
        yield
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

I then called this in another script:

```
from sql_server_connection import open_db_connection
with open_db_connection(server, database) as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query_string, conn)
```

which raises this error:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 436, in read_sql_query
    return pandas_sql.read_query(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2116, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 2054, in execute
    cur = self.con.cursor()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

I didn't define a cursor here because I expect that `Pandas` handle it as it did before I think about closing the connection. If the approach above is wrong how would I close the connection? Or does `pyodbc` handle it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You yield nothing (`None`) from your `open_db_connection`.

```py
import pyodbc
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_db_connection(server, database):
    """
    Context manager to automatically close DB connection. 
    """
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    try:
        yield conn  # yield the connection not None
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Also, I should point out two things:

1. pyodbc does not expect the user to close the connections ([docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#close)):

> Connections are automatically closed when they are deleted (typically when they go out of scope) so you should not normally need to call this, but you can explicitly close the connection if you wish.

2. pandas expects a SQLAlchemy connectable, a SQLAlchemy URL str or a [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) connections in its `read_sql_*` functions ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query)), not a pyODBC connection, so your mileage may vary.

> ##### `pandas.read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, params=None, parse_dates=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)`
>
> `con`: SQLAlchemy connectable, str, or sqlite3 connection
>
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.

---

I would probably simplify to the following:

No need for error handling, this function **must** return a connection (also split up the string on several line and used f-strings rather than concat).

```py
import pyodbc

def open_db_connection(server, database):
    """
    Context manager to automatically close DB connection. 
    """
    return pyodbc.connect(
        "DRIVER={SQL Server};"
        f"SERVER={server};"
        f"DATABASE={database};"
        "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
    )
```

Call the above function directly in the argument list to scope the connection to inside `read_sql_query`. Might want to do error handling here as well, but that depends on what you're writing.

```py
import pandas as pd

from sql_server_connection import open_db_connection

df = pd.read_sql_query(
    query_string,
    open_db_connection(server, database),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. It helped me a lot. Another question: the script calls the database every one hour in an infinite loop (while True: time.sleep(x)). Considering that, is it still ok not to close the connection?

Comment: With your context manager, the connection falls out of scope and can/will be closed automatically, same goes for my "create connection in function call". I recommend you read up on python scope and see what works best for you. Also pyODBC might make it look like the connection is opened and closed, but the underlying unixODBC does connection pooling which you can also read about.